# add captcha to identityserver3

Tags: captcha, identityserver3

currently my sso server is identityserver. I need to make the third failed attempt to enter a captcha is displayed and be validated by entering username and password. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, Check out the [CustomViewService](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomViewService). All you need to do is add the client side code for [captcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) and youre good to go

Comment: thanks for your answer, it has helped me. But it is possible to obtain the value of the authentication and stored in the view model and the method AuthenticateLocalAsync read the view model to know if I should read or not the result of captcha addition to making the decision the view model if I show in the view or do not. I only need that. Thank you!